# Erro no projeto baixado do github com JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

Eu fiz o download de um projeto do github (Projeto fj25-financas-web - Caelum) e adicionei esse projeto no JBoss 7.1.1. Quando o executo, ocorrem esses erros:

```
16:07:15,515 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6)     MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.fj25-financas-web.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.fj25-financas-web.war".main: Failed to load   module: deployment.fj25-financas-web.war:main
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: Module org.hibernate.search.orm:main is not found in local module loader @af7b86 (roots: C:\Users\Frederico\PROJETOS_JAVA\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:126) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:275) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:222) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:94) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:841) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1181) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1207) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:208) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
16:07:15,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:07:15,561 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 9327ms - Started 146 of 275 services (1 services failed or missing dependencies, 126 services are passive or on-demand)
16:07:15,780 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "fj25-financas-web.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fj25-financas-web.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fj25-financas-web.war\".main: Failed to load module: deployment.fj25-financas-web.war:main"}}
16:07:15,796 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment fj25-financas-web.war in 22ms
16:07:15,811 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)  JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.module.service."deployment.fj25-financas-web.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.fj25-financas-web.war".main: Failed to load module: deployment.fj25-financas-web.war:main

16:07:15,811 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fj25-financas-web.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.fj25-financas-web.war\".main: Failed to load module: deployment.fj25-financas-web.war:main"}}}}
```

Comment: Parece problema de classpath. Em especial, a falta do JAR do hibernatesearch.

Comment: Sim, mas o problema e como inserir no nas pastas do Jboss, porque so no eclipse no buildpath nao funciona.

Comment: O jboss tem uma pasta de libs. Dá uma olhada se as libs estão nela.